# Embedded class and bi-directional relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This question is very hard for me to formulate. Feel free to ask if clarification is needed.

**Situation:** I have a Spring-Application using Hibernate to persist different Entity-Classes in a database. For simplification calling these classes `E1, E2, .., E20`. All these classes are based on the same abstract `@MappedSuperclass` but have no real inheritance (on the database side).

Now I want to add new Entity-Classes (`En1, En2, ...`) and establish bi-directional relations to a few of the existing entities. Assuming `En1`is in a realtion with `E1,E2,E3`, my code looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class E1 extends SuperClass {
  //other attributes

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "e1")
  List<En1> newAttribut;

  public En1 doMagic(En1 entity) {
    //a long function which does somthing with the entity
  }

  //other attribute
} 

//-----------------------------//
// The same code for E2 and E3 //
//-----------------------------//

@Entity
public class En1 {
  //other attributes

  @ManyToOne
  E1 e1;

  @ManyToOne
  E2 e2;

  @ManyToOne
  E3 e3;

  //other attributes
}
```

**Problem:** This solution scales not well. I need an attribut in the class `En1` for each relation and a must copy the `doMagic()` method in each existing entity. Furthermore, in practise the entity `En1` will only by in a relation with one other entity at a time. So two out of three attributes wil be `null`.

**Tried Solution:** The usage of `@Embeddable` solves the issue of reimplementing the same code in `E1,..,E3`

```
public class EmbeddedEn1 implements Serializable {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentEntity")
  private List<En1> newAttribut;

  public En1 doMagic(En1 entity) {
    //a long function which does somthing with the new entity
  } 
}
```

But the `"parentEntity"` bi-diretion can not be established.

**Inheritance is not working:** Of course, I could use a class like `hasAttributEn1` which `E1,E2,E3` inherit from, but this does not scale with the other new Entity-Classes. Assuming the following situation, in which the new entities `En2,..,En4` should be in relation to the following entities:

- `En2 <-> E1,   E3`
- `En3 <->    E2,E3`
- `En4 <-> E1,E2`

In this situation, multiple inheritance would be needed.

Any suggestions how to solve this issue without duplicating code?

Answer (score 1):

I think to better solve your model, you may use [hibernate inheritance](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Inheritance.html).

+So for the case of entity `En1`, Create a parent class for `E1,E2,E3...`:

```
@Entity
// TABLE_PER_CLASS will create a table for each subclass with all attributes
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
//....
//Abstract entity, so you won't need to create a table for it
public abstract class E extends SuperClass {

   // shared attributes & methods
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "e")
   private List<En> newAttribut; 

   public En doMagic(En entity) {
       //a long function which does something with the new entity
   }
   //...
```

}

- Delete `doMagic(En1)` and `newAttribute` from your `E1,E2,E3`, as they will inherit them from the parent class `E`

**Update**:

As you mentioned in your comment (and in your question as well), you need to associate `E` class with more than one `En` classes. 
To make it simple I will use hibernate inheritance for `En` as well:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class En{

    @ManyToOne
    private E e;

    // ...

}
```

So each `En1, En2,..., Enx` will inherit from this class.

For example, if you want to save `En2 <-> E3` & `En3 <->E3` (this example is for illustration purpose, and does not cover other aspects like transaction):

```
En en2 = new En2();        
En en3 = new En3();
E e3 = new E3();     
en2.setE(e3);
e3.getEn().add(en2);

en3.setE(e3);
e3.getEn().add(en3);
session.save(e3)
session.save(en2)
session.save(en3)
```

At the end you will satisfy your constraints:

- One copy of `doMagin()` method,
- Sub-Entity of `En` (e.g:`En1`) will only have an association with only one other entity (e.g: `E1` or `E3`) at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this is exactly the solution which will not work for multiple `En*`. In my question **Inheritance is not working** I tried to explain why. I can make abstract classes like `class hasEn1` as shown in your example code, but since `En2` should also be in relation to `E1` I would need multiple inheritance for the `E1` class like `class E1 extends hasEn1,hasEn2`, which is not allowed in Java.

Comment: @Thanthla I've updated the answer to cover the second case.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to define generic types for E1,E2,...,E20 so that you only would need to define your En classes with a single collection of E types. Each implementation for E can be different but you wont need to change your En classes because it simply just hold a collection of the E types.

[Here's a link to a guide that may help.](http://www.baeldung.com/simplifying-the-data-access-layer-with-spring-and-java-generics)

Comment: I am using generic DAOs in my project. But this questions corresponds to the model structure, i.e., the design of the entities, and not the way I can access them.